# What branch of math do I need to learn to understand and use math for procedural animation?

Tags: mathematics, animation

I watched a video about procedural animation from **t3ssel8r** channel - [**YouTube video link**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPoeNZZ6H4s). I was interested in this topic - programming curves and various dependencies, but I'm not strong in mathematics.

I want to know what section of mathematics I need to learn in order to understand what is happening in the video and how it happens, how to create my own curves and procedural animation using mathematics.

Can you advise me?

[image]

Comment: Looks like high-school Calculus to me. Derivatives are a common concept in the study of a function, and many academic concepts apply here along with additional considerations of practical nature.

Comment: Keyword that is not explicitly shown in the video is [Damping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping). It describes the effect of resistance on an object in oscillation. (just think about a spring). This is definitely overkill for me, Easier and more customizable using Unity's out-of-the-box [curve](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EditingCurves.html) system.

Comment: Didn't watch the video, but if it's talking about curves then you want to understand polynomials and Bezier curves (neither is very difficult). Some algebra and calculus is useful if you want to join multiple curves in a continuous way end-to-end.

Comment: Try [Essence of linear algebra](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab) and [Essence of calculus](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr) by 3blue1brown. Perhaps try Khan Academy if you need to reinforce some concepts. I'm voting to close the question.